# Unable to play sounds on Android Game Build using Cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova, audio, soundjs

Please can someone help me- this is driving me crazy!!!

I have created a HTML5 project which uses PreloadJS and SoundJS to play some sounds. It works absolutely fine in Chrome but when I push it to Cordova Emulator (Android SDK) or to my Android mobile, it builds and deploys successfully, but I get no sound at all and I can't figure out why. The Android monitor shows the following errors but I am not sure if they relate to SoundJS:

```
•I/MediaFocusControl(1258): AudioFocus requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager @ b303c1a8com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@b30f0238

•E/MediaPlayer(1904): error (1, -2147483648)
```

I am trying to fire the sound on a button click event so I don't think it is related to a security issue.

I am pre-loading the sound files using the following code:

```
p.assetsPath = 'assets/';

p.initialize = function () {

   this.EventDispatcher_initialize();

   this.loadManifest = [
      {id:this.MENUSOUNDTRACK, src:this.assetsPath + 'MainTrack.ogg'},
      {id:this.GAMESOUNDTRACK, src:this.assetsPath + 'BackingTrack.ogg'},
 .......
}

p.preloadAssets = function () {
   createjs.Sound.initializeDefaultPlugins();
   createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];

   this.queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
   this.queue.on('progress',this.assetsProgress,this);
   this.queue.on('complete',this.assetsLoaded,this);

   this.queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);        
   this.queue.loadManifest(this.loadManifest);
}
```

All of the sound files are stored in /www/assets which I believe should be automatically mapped to /android_asset/www/assets by cordova.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see some discussion around using PhoneGap [here](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/soundjs/1602-soundjs-phonegap) which will likely be relevant.

In theory everything should work with Cordova, but it is not well tested.

I would suggest making sure all sounds are loaded completely before attempting playback, making sure you are using the latest version of soundjs from [github](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/), and testing one of the simple examples from github to confirm if its a SoundJS and Cordova issue or if there is something in your implementation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Ojay, Thanks for you message.  i have stumbled across that link when trying to find a fix, but it concludes that they couldn't get it to work, so used another library. I was hoping that some one would say they definitely had soundjs working and how they did it... (And then I can work out why my code is off the mark)

Comment: They note early on that the [mobile safe approach](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/) does work in phonegap.

[Work](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/pull/37) has been done to help SoundJS work with phonegap, but its not something we test against.

Comment: Hi OJay - whatever I try, I can't get SoundJs working with Cordova and Android. So frustrating as I love CreateJS and EaselJS.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  We've considered added a plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap but its not something we've had time to implement.  I keep hoping someone in the community will put one together and add a pull request to the repo.